# Php Excel set whole column data alignment not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am Using this code For E column data set to right align but Its not showing me effect

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('E')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

instead of 'E' if i write E6 then it display E6 cell data to right.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('E6')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're correct: row and column styles aren't supported by PHPExcel.

Cell styling is, but you can also set style by a range of cells:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('E1:E256')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

Comment: but as i search and found in some example of other site and they provide the example with whole column alignment. Thats why i was confused. I was thinking that i am missing something.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @pankil - If you have an example of setting a row or column style (e.g. alignment), then please provide it; and I'll stand corrected

Comment: The answer by Jijesh Cherrai is a better answer.

Comment: @Mark Baker Seems you can help me again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733202/how-can-i-set-text-align-right-in-the-column-on-the-laravel-excel-maatwebsite

Comment: FWIW, `PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT` is  `"right"`.  I suppose it's possible that the constant will change but it's probably safe, more readable and easier to remember `setHorizontal('right')`

Answer (score 11):

Since nobody explained how to style an entire column, which was part of the question, here's the code:

```
$lastrow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('E1:E'.$lastrow)
        ->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this code. It works well.And I have confirmed.

```
 $activeSheet = $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet();
    //..
    //...
     $activeSheet->getStyle("E")
                 ->getAlignment()
                 ->setHorizontal(\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

This code align the column E in horizontal right

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: @KolobCanyon - Does this answer actually work? It doesn't on any of the PHPExcel code that I work with

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I added screen shots here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816644/format-the-cells-for-entire-column-in-php-excel

Comment: If it works, how come you're posting a question saying that it doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkBaker  Both your answer and Jijesh Cherrai formats a range of cells within a column, but not the whole column itself. I'm asking a question about the implications of this. Technically that means it does work. I said this answer was better because you don't need to specify the range of cells. I think that is justified.

Comment: Except that it doesn't work (whether it should or not is a different matter)..... believe me, I think I'd know if it was possible, I wrote the code in the first place

Comment: I tried this with version 1.8 and it in fact did not work. Does not apply any formatting to any cells since "E" isn't treated as a range.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed this as well while trying to apply certain number formats to colums: you cannot apply a style to a column - *getStyle('E')*, you must specify the range - *getStyle('E1:E50')*.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row_array, NULL, 'A2');
$rows = count($row_array);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C2:C'.$rows)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('000000000');
```

This code will left-pad the numbers in column C with zeros

Comment: it's been a while but I just bumped into this question and this works         **$activeSheet->getStyle('A')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('right');**

Comment: this too **$activeSheet->getStyle('A')->getFill()->setFillType('solid')->getStartColor()->setARGB('00FF0000');**. I'm starting to think maybe it's been added to later versions since 2013. Yes, I think that's it; Jijesh's post is correct and from 2014