# Center Text vertical and horizontal in PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I try to style my spreadsheet with the PHPSpreadsheet calls.
I want to center the text vertical and horizontal.
What I do is this:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Name');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
...
...
...
foreach (range('A', 'E') as $columnID) {
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($columnID)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('center');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($columnID)->getAlignment()->setVertical('center');
}
```

But when I open the excel file, the text is not centered.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Ok the problem is, it is not working with range.
You need to do this:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
```

You have to add the cell **number**

Comment: It may be down to the format of the column you try to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/13307949/1213708 suggests the range should be something like `->getStyle('E1:E256')`.